# Can we add vertical ScrollView dynamically to the table row in table layout

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

I have a tablelayout in xml file and I am adding table row programmatically .Can I add vertical scrollview dynamically  to the table row only .

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: yes you can, enjoy happy coding :P